# преобразование десятичного числа в двоичное

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int convertdecimaltobinary(int n);
int main (void)
{
    int decimalnumber;
    printf ("Введите десятичное число\n");
    scanf("%d",&decimalnumber);
    printf ("%d = %d", decimalnumber, 
convertdecimaltobinary(decimalnumber));
    return 0 ;
}
int convertdecimaltobinary(int n)
{
    int binarynumber=0,remainder,i=1;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        remainder=n%2;
        n/=2;
        binarynumber= binarynumber + remainder*i;
        i=i*10;

    }
    return binarynumber;
}
```

`i=i*10;` не могу понять зачем и как работает эта строчка, вчера часов 6 пытался сам решить задачку и получалась фигня, поэтому если можете, то объясните пожалуйста подробно, буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Чтоб остаток в нужный разряд попадал. Сначала в единицы, потом в десятки и т.д. Только вот назвать это "*преобразованием в двоичное число*" - как по мне, издевательство. Это преобразование в десятичное число, имеющее ту же запись, что и соответствующее двоичное представление.

Comment: @Harry Так чтобы остаток в нужный разряд попадал нужно же умножать на 10 и добавлять остаток, а тут получается что условно при 5 проходе цикла число будет умножаться на 100000

Comment: Так ведь вы же идете справа налево...

Comment: @Harry, Но умножение то идет слева направо, какая мне разница откуда идти,если вместо "бинарного числа" у меня будет 1000000000100100001. Это конечно в моем представлении, но программа выполняется правильно